# Sync Animated Plots

Tags: manipulate

Here is my Lorenz code:

```
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == -10 (x[t] - y[t]), 
  y'[t] == -x[t] z[t] + 24.74 x[t] - y[t], 
  z'[t] == x[t] y[t] - 8/3 z[t], x[0] == 3, y[0] == 5, 
  z[0] == 8}, {x[t], y[t], z[t]}, {t, 0, 100}, MaxSteps -> Infinity]
```

Here is `x[t]` vs `z[t]` and `x[t]` vs `t`:

```
p = ParametricPlot[{x[t], z[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 30}];
pdata = p[[1, 1, 3, 2, 1]];
Manipulate[
  ListLinePlot[pdata[[1 ;; m]], PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {0, 45}}], {m,
  1, Length[pdata], 1}]

p2 = Plot[x[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 30}];
p2data = p2[[1, 1, 3, 2, 1]];
Manipulate[
  ListLinePlot[p2data[[1 ;; m]], 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {-18, 18}}], {m, 1, Length[pdata], 1}]
```

Is it possible run `p` and `p2` simultaneously in sync?

Comment: Look up `GraphicsRow[]`, `GraphicsColumn[]`, or `GraphicsGrid[]`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `LocalizeVariables` option:

```
Manipulate[
 ListLinePlot[pdata[[1 ;; m]], PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {0, 45}}],
 {m, 1, Length[pdata], 1}, LocalizeVariables -> False],

Manipulate[
 ListLinePlot[p2data[[1 ;; m]], PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {-18, 18}}],
 {m, 1, Length[pdata], 1}, LocalizeVariables -> False]
```

[image]

But you should be clear that you can put really anything inside Manipulate. You could put a 1000x1000 grid of live cat videos in one Manipulate, if your computer was capable (mine cannot handle so much cat).

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for your data extraction, so I'm not using your `pdata = p[[1, 1, 3, 2, 1]]`, etc.:

```
Manipulate[ GraphicsRow@{
   Plot[x[t] /. sol,                   {t, 0, m}, PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {-18, 18}}], 
   ParametricPlot[{x[t], z[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, m}, PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {0, 45}}, 
                  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]}, 
{m, 10^-6, 30}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I usually prefer `Grid` over `GraphicsGrid` and the like:

```
Manipulate[Grid@{{
    ListLinePlot[pdata[[1 ;; m]],
     PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {0, 45}},
     ImageSize -> 300]},
   {ListLinePlot[p2data[[1 ;; m]],
     PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {-18, 18}},
     ImageSize -> 300]}},
 {m, 1, Length[pdata], 1}]
```

Comment: Yea, I usually use just Column/Row or even a simple List.